# What does "at 2 times book" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

And is there any mistake in the writer's using "a year from now" here? I think it should be "a year ago".

"Then there's the valuation to consider. Deutsche Bank shares are selling at half their expected book value **a year from now**, while UBS looked like a bargain to GIC **at 2 times book**."

Source: https://www.bloomberg.com/gadfly/articles/2017-05-16/hna-can-avoid-singapore-s-ubs-sour-grapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... half their **expected** book value **a year from now**...

This is correct, meaning the price at which they are predicted to be selling a year from now is twice what they are selling for today.

> ... **at 2 times book.** means at twice the [book value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_value), or twice the generally accepted value based on a valuation according to traditional accounting practices.

Comment: Why does the author shift to past tense "... while UBS looked like a bargain"?  "are selling ... while UBS looked" is an odd construction.

Comment: Agreed, odd choice. I decline to speculate on the reasons, but there may be some.